# building setup on python using cx freeze gives error on mac os but runs fine on windows

Tags: macos, cx-freeze, setup.py, darwin

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
packages = ['requests', 'binance']
include_files = ['settings.ini']
setup(name="PD Unonymous",
  version="2",
  description="PD Unonymous BOT for Binance",
  author="Denocyte",
  options={
      'build_exe': {
          'packages': packages,
          'include_files': include_files
      }
  },
  executables=[Executable(
      script="main.py",
      icon="icon.ico"
  )])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 6, in 
setup(name="PD Unonymous",
..........
cx_Freeze.darwintools.DarwinException: resolveRPath() failed to resolve path: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Python3